# Android honeycomb-like pattern for data from adapter

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-adapter

Is it possible in Android to implement strategy of positioning for provided by Adapter elements like this (see image)?

[image]

Also in future I would like to make this bubbles interact with each other, react on touches. Could you please recommend some strategies (maybe, physics engines) to do this?

Comment: I think RelativeLayout may help to do such design.

Comment: `RecyclerView` + custom `LayoutManager`

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev thanks a lot for this idea, could you please add more details?

Comment: @Sergii well, can't add much. That would be a highly reusable solution, but definitely not an easy one and you'll probably spend hours trying to understand how `LayoutManager` works :)